# need to split parameter in mysql by operator "-"

Tags: mysql

Getting `**359616044513513-2574**`
 as Mysql parameter, my requirement is to split this parameter by **"-"** operater and stored them into two variables like 
     `dev=359616044513513 and id=2574`
How can i do it in stored procedure of MYSQL??

Comment: In T-SQL, you could use CHARINDEX to find the first occurrence of '-' and then SUBSTRING to divide it. Check if those functions are available for MYSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(IN my_param TEXT) BEGIN
  DECLARE dev TEXT DEFAULT SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_param, '-',  1);
  DECLARE id  TEXT DEFAULT SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_param, '-', -1);

  -- etc.
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```